# Cholesky decomposition: any theoretical value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factoring

Just read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) on Cholesky decomposition. All the applications listed there were numerical. Are there theoretical arguments to which it is important?

For instance, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) there is an argument that for $M,N$ symmetric, $M>0$, we have that there exists a matrix $X$ such that $X^TMX$ and $X^TNX$ are both diagonal. They use the Cholesky decomposition, but it seems the argument works equally well with factoring $M = \left( \sqrt{M} \right)^2$. Incidentally, I'm having trouble with this argument.

Comment: Well, my first thought is that the square root of a matrix need not always exist, and when it does it isn't uniquely defined.  That usually messes with attempts to use it in a proof.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I believe the Cholesky decomposition only applies to positive definite matrices as well, though.

Comment: Hm, I cannot really pinpoint the problem which you are actually focusing. But one important property of the Cholesky -factors is, that -besides they are just their mutual transposes - they are triangular. Additionally, if you allow "robust" cholesky decompositions (which does not break, if zeros occur on the diagonal) then you can also allow positive semidefinite matrices - this allows analytic argumentation with the cholesky decomposition also for this wider class of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

My personal best of the theoretical importance of the Cholesky factorisation is the ease with which you can prove its existence. Assuming $x^TMx>0$, it takes only few lines to show that there is an $N$ such that $M=N^TN$. You don't need to refer to matrix square roots and other kinds of "magic" tools which heavily rely on eigenvalue decompositions.

**EDIT:** I do not remember, where I saw this proof exactly. It is easy to prove it using induction. The $1\times 1$ case is trivial, assume it's true for $n$ and consider an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ SPD matrix
$$\tag{1}
\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & a^T \\ a & A
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It's easy to eliminate $a$'s by
$$\tag{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ -\alpha^{-1}a & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & a^T \\ a & A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\alpha^{-1}a^T \\ 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & A-\alpha^{-1}aa^T
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now it would be good if $A-\alpha^{-1}aa^T$ was positive definite, since if $A-\alpha^{-1}aa^T=LL^T$ for some lower triangular $L$, then
$$
\tilde{L}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ \alpha^{-1}a & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{a} & 0 \\
0 & L
\end{bmatrix}
$$
would be the Cholesky factor of (1). That $A-\alpha^{-1}aa^T$ is SPD can be easily deduced from (2): The matrix $\tilde{A}$ is SPD by assumption, so $x^T\tilde{A}x>0$ for all nonzero $x$, so it certainly is true also for all $x$ of the form $x=[-\alpha^{-1}a^Ty,y^T]$ where $y\neq 0$, for which we have
$$
y^T(A-\alpha^{-1}aa^T)y=x^T\tilde{A}x>0.
$$

P.S.: When I wrote few lines, I thought actually "few lines of formulas" :-)

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find such a proof? Wikipedia seems to do it by row elimination or SVD. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @EricAuld I don't remember where I saw the proof by induction, so I've tried to reproduce it.